# How to "scan" all sharedpreference key's to save her in a list

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

in the passed, to display graph ( time/value) I saved data with sharedpref like that :

//After press button I listen date and use $current_date like a variable key

```
set( $current_date_key; value)
```

But user can press randomly the button and I can't determine what $current_date the user saved.

So I would know how to create a function like a scan ( for loop) who increase time with a step of minutes and save in a list all values found.

for example if I have a datenow format like 19/08/2020_13:12 I want to iterate with a step like

```
    19/08/2020 13:11 
    19/08/2020 13:10  
    19/08/2020 13:09

...
    19/08/2018 05:08
```

And save in a list[] all key's who are value different of 0

for example :

```
 //   if I have
            19/08/2020 13:11 =0
            19/08/2020 13:10 =0
            19/08/2020 13:09 =1
            19/08/2020 13:08 =0
            19/08/2020 13:07 =1
    
    I search to save in List[19/08/2020 13:09, 19/08/2020 13:07]
```

it's possible ?

Thank you

Comment: So you want a list of all keys that are stored in `SharedPreferences` right?

Answer (score 1):

To get all the keys which are currently stored in `SharedPreferences`, you can use [`getKeys()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/getKeys.html) function. It returns a `Set` which you can convert to a `List` using `toList()`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
List<String> keys = prfes.getKeys().toList();
```

Comment: not exactly what I search but it can work in my case, it's seems more simple :) I will try, thank you